# I want to render objects depending on other objects y coords

Tags: java, object, render

In my game, I have a player, enemies, and upgrades that enemies drop.

Upgrades are rendered first, then the player, and then enemies, but I want my player to behind objects that have a greater Y value than the player, and I want my player to be in front of objects with a smaller Y value than the player.

OK, OK. Here's my render class.

```
package main;

import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Render extends JPanel {
    public Game game;

    public Render(Game game) {
        this.game = game;
    }

   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        game.world.render(g);
        game.tile.render(g);

        game.upgrade.render(g);

        game.player.render(g);
        game.bullet.render(g);
        game.gun.render(g);
        game.sword.render(g);

        game.soldier.render(g);
        game.blood.render(g);

        game.hud.render(g);
    }

}
```

I have no idea how to go about doing this. If someone could give me some example code, that would be awesome.

***Again, what I want to do is render objects with larger Y values infront of objects with smaller Y values.***

I didn't really find anything on Stack Overflow that I could understand too well, either.

Thank you.

Comment: Your question would be better if you could tell us the important details of your problem and show pertinent code. These details include which GUI library you're using, how your currently rendering your items. If Swing then the order of rendering is very important and will determine the z-order of the images.

Comment: The first object you paint will be on the bottom. The second will be on top. So structure your painting logic as required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty simple: sort all objects (including the player) by their y-coordinates descending. And render them by this order.

```
public void render(Graphics g){
    List<ElementType> elements = new ArrayList<>();
    elements.add(player);
    elements.add(title);
    ...

    //sort the list such that elements with higher y-value at lower indices than elements
    //with lower y-value
    Collections.sort(elements , (a , b) -> Integer.compare(b.getY() - a.getY());

    for(ElementType element : elements)
        element.render(g);
}
```

Note that this requires that all elements that are rendered inherit from `ElementType`, which needs to implement `getY()` and `render(Graphics).`ElementType`can either be an`interface`or`(abstract) class` with arbitrary name, just replace the names with the ones matching your code.

Comment: Yes, that sounds like what I want, but I have no idea how to do this. This i my first time. Any suggestions on how I could code that?

Comment: Add all elements to a `Collection`, sort it (`Collections.sort(...)`) and render the resulting `Collection` in the given order. I'll edit the post